# Wordpress plugin that can check laravel $user-> access_level, Get laravel user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, plugins, customization

I am currently having a Laravel site using laravel auth. In one of my links on the site, I want it to link to a child url to lead to a page with child pages controlled by wordpress.

The content on the page needs to be restricted access based on the laravel user auth. 2 components are required:

1. Laravel integration
2. Wordpress plugin that can check laravel $user-> access_level, display it, and restrict access to certain page for users. Please describe the solution to this problem and how it would be implemented.

Comment: Do you have any solution in your mind?

Comment: @Nitish no idea about this

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49025277/470749

Answer (score 1):

I dressed Lumen as a Wp Theme in order to achieve exactly the same problem.

https://github.com/rogervila/wplumen (Now its outdated, but you can create a similar solution)

All requests are cached by Lumen, which controls all routes, auth, etc.

Then, the routes not used on Lumen, fall back to the WP Router, like the admin pages (edit.php, etc...)

I hope it helps.

Comment: On the themes folder. For example: /wp-content/themes/wplumen

Comment: When active theme then i have face this error: please open this link: 
 https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/828838/mkm3meritpuxb3zovsd8

Comment: You have to run composer install