# Auth user from Laravel to Wordpress Database

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, authentication

I have a existing site in wordpress. User register only by web (wordpress). How to authenticate user from Laravel to the wordpress DB.

Comment: you can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication for that, it has built-in Auth mechanism, which operates on `users` table

Comment: but i have to use the wordpress database.

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41813124/470749

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. You could:

- Use a custom authentication driver on your Laravel app to use WordPress database. [Hampel's package](https://packagist.org/packages/hampel/wordpress-auth-laravel) does this.
- Use a custom authentication provider to authenticate WordPress users. [Laravel WP User package](https://github.com/CalderaWP/laravel-wp-user) can do this, and it also support REST API.
- Override Laravel's hashing to make WordPress compatible password hashes using [Laravel WP Password package](https://github.com/mikemclin/laravel-wp-password). You can [read more about this here](https://medium.com/@mangia/share-users-between-wordpress-and-laravel-a536d54499bb).
- [Replace WordPress's built-in authentication](https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/7175/wordpress-replace-built-in-user-authentication).
- Use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/authenticate/laravel/wordpress/).

There are probably still [more ways to do this](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+laravel+authentication).