# Wordpress authentication with using Laravel Session and tables

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, session

I created a WordPress folder on my Laravel public folder. Now I want to check if users are authenticated on my WordPress index.php. But I can not access Laravel's session data. Are there any idea about that.

My folder Structure is:

[image]

Also my web.php file is;

```
 Route::get('/content', 'SubscribedPagesController@content');
```

Also my controller is:

```
class SubscribedPagesController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct() {
         $this->middleware('auth');
     }

     public function content(Request $request){
         $request->session()->push('myuser', Auth::user());
         return redirect('/wordpress');
     }
}
```

And I am trying this one on WordPress index.php:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['user']); //also, I can not access any session variable.
```

A note: it is not working for https://www..com/wordpress, too.

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49025277/470749

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access Laravel session data using the global PHP `session` function:

`session( 'user' )`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session

Laravel doesn't seem to use PHP sessions anymore (depending on your version), so you won't be able to access session data through ie `_SESSION`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but session() function is undefined in wordpress. I should create a mutual session between laravel and wordpress

Comment: @devneeddev could you pls share how you implemented mutual session?